# Vimeo API:Removing the list of 'More from...' videos displayed at the end of a played video

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am embedding links to Vimeo videos in our website using the API. 
Using the API, I am able to upload videos and change privacy settings.
But is possible to remove the list of 'More from (my company name) ...' videos after a video plays?

```
                VimeoClient vimeoClient = new VimeoClient("6456456456 our api key asdfasdf");
                BinaryContent binaryContent = new BinaryContent(stream, "video/mp4");
                var uploadRequest = await vimeoClient.UploadEntireFileAsync(binaryContent);

                VimeoDotNet.Models.VideoUpdateMetadata videoData = new VimeoDotNet.Models.VideoUpdateMetadata();
                videoData.EmbedPrivacy = VimeoDotNet.Enums.VideoEmbedPrivacyEnum.Public;
                videoData.Privacy = VimeoDotNet.Enums.VideoPrivacyEnum.Unlisted;
                videoData.ReviewLinkEnabled = false;
                await vimeoClient.UpdateVideoMetadataAsync(uploadRequest.ClipId.Value, videoData);

                adminPortalViewModel.Hyperlink = @"https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + uploadRequest.ClipId;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the embed.end_screen.type to 'empty' or other options when upload the video:

see https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/response/embed-settings

I personally use settings like the following to create upload link in the backend and upload the video in the frontend:

```js
{
    "upload": {
        "approach": "tus",
        "size": video_size
        },
    'name':video_name,
    'description':video_description,
    'privacy': {
        'view': 'disable',
        'download':'false',
        'add':'false',
        'comments':'nobody',
        'embed':'whitelist',
        },
    'embed':{
        'volumn':'true',
        'logos':{
            'vimeo':'false',
            'customs':{
                'active':'false',
                'sticky':'false',
            },
        },
        'title':{
            'name':'hide',
            'owner':'hide',
            'portrait':'hide',
        },
        'buttons':{
            'embed':'false',
            'like':'false',
            'share':'false',
            'watchlater':'false',
        },
        'end_screen':{
            'type':'empty'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I did not find a way through the API to modify individual videos.
However, by logging into your account and selecting ... Settings/Videos/Embed presets/(choose album) /End Screens, will give you a dropdown list that you can modify what shows at the end.
We chose 'Text' with no text in the textbox. This is a global setting, but it worked for our needs.
I do believe you have to be a pro user to have this available.

Answer (score 1):

Updated Vimeo End Screen options:

https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007893267

> All the options listed above can be found by navigating to your
>   video's settings > Interaction tools > After video. Open the End
>   screen drop-down menu to choose your end screen.